# Parallel processing in Openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, parallel-processing, openpyxl

Im attempting to run some quite large code which requires parallel processing in order to be time efficient.

In short I have a master excel workbook created with openpyxl from which i both read and write to.

I then have 3 additional work books which I load in and using the data from those I write to the relevant cells in the master workbook. This also requires reading the previous number from the cell in the master workbook which is being appended in order to cumulate the number in the cell.

I want to be able to run the 3 workbooks in parallel and read and write to the master workbook at the same time.

So far i've tried running it in parralel using the built in python functionality as well as ray. But each time it just returns the master workbook with all the numbers that should have been appended in the functions as missing. The remainder of the workbook is populated by all the actions that i have done outside the functions.

I've tested the code without multiprocessing and it works as intended but is extremely slow, hence the need for running the functions in parallel. So there are no errors in the code.

The code is proprietary but the operations can be summed as follows:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font, NamedStyle
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter

master_workbook = Workbook()
ws1 = master_workbook.active
ws1.title = "Sample"

'''
Code containing cell formatting
'''

def child_1():
    child_1 = load_workbook(filename = "C:\\Somesamplefile1.xlsx", data_only=True, read_only=True)
    sheet_1 = child_1["Sheet1"]

    for i, x in range(0, 10): 
        example_fetch_from_child = sheet_1.cell(row=10, column=2+i).value

        example_write_to_master_val = ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).value
        if example_write_to_master_val is None:
            ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).value = 0
        ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).value = ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).value + example_fetch_from_child
        ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).style = "number_default_style"

        '''
        These operations continue for a while, but the gist is that I'm fetching data from a child workbook, and writing it to the master workbook.
        '''

def child_2():
    child_2 =  load_workbook(filename = "C:\\Somesamplefile2.xlsx", data_only=True, read_only=True)
    sheet_1 = child_2["Sheet1"]

    for i, x in range(0, 10): 
        example_fetch_from_child = sheet_1.cell(row=10, column=2+i).value

        example_write_to_master_val = ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).value
        if example_write_to_master_val is None:
            ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).value = 0
        ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).value = ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).value + example_fetch_from_child
        ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).style = "number_default_style"

def child_3():
    child_3 = load_workbook(filename = "C:\\Somesamplefile3.xlsx", data_only=True, read_only=True)
    sheet_1 = child_3["Sheet1"]

    for i, x in range(0, 10): 
        example_fetch_from_child = sheet_1.cell(row=10, column=2+i).value

        example_write_to_master_val = ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).value
        if example_write_to_master_val is None:
            ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).value = 0
        ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).value = ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).value + example_fetch_from_child
        ws1.cell(row=12, column=2+i).style = "number_default_style"

child_1()
child_2()
child_3()

'''
Do some more formatting and minor actions
'''

master_workbook.save(filename = "C:\\Someoutputfile.xlsx")
```

Comment: You can't parallelise writing code but you can read in parallel. You could optimise your reads, because ad hoc is slow in read-only mode.

Comment: While a goal seems clear, the tools selected to reach such goal seem to lack the wished to have properties. (A) Python, as-of 2023-05 and perhaps forever, as Giudo has explained, will lack any chance to get any faster if thread-based tools are used -- the central GIL-monopolistic-re-[SERIAL]-iser still keeps the flow of work as a pure-[SERIAL], round-robin series in a one-WORKs-all-other-WAIT ( so zero acceleration appears, perhaps some latency masking can happen on async/url interactions, nothing more ) (B) process-based split of work copies the **whole Python process** many times at costs

Comment: (C) if your attempts to thus (see [B] ) way operate N-many concurrently opened "source"-xlsx-files, you rely on these N-many replicas to success in writing results into a single, concurrently written-to "result"-xlsx-file ( if the OpenPyXL tool permits that to do so ). Resulting performance, due to [A]+[B]+[C] might be even worse, than in a single thread, single process, zero concurrent writes into the "result:-xlsx-file if swaps and/or { dead-lock | live-lock }-collisions or many concurrent write attempts try to re-write parts inside the "result"-xlsx-file.

Comment: @CharlieClark as for optimizing my reads, how would I go about doing so? I believe its already optimized according to openpyxl's documentation on the matter (using read_only=true)

Comment: As I said, you have ad hoc calls. The documentation warns against these in read-only mode.

Comment: @CharlieClark im not quite sure what you mean by ad hoc calls. I've looked around in the documentation and find no mention of it. Said in another way, what should I do instead to achieve the desired effect?